# How can I use two different ruby installations for same project with rvm and rvmrc files?

Tags: rvm

I have a an app that runs and is installed on JRuby in production. The same app can run in Ruby 1.8.7 as well in development. How can I use RVM to switch between these rubie?

I am looking for a `.rvmrc`-like solution so that I can say

```
rvm use .rvmrc_ruby
```

or

```
rvm use .rvmrc_jruby
```

to switch between Ruby versions. I usually need to do this to test the same app on both Ruby and JRuby.

I would like a solution where I can check-in such settings to Git and run these things without having to type the Ruby versions or gemset names everytime I need to switch.

Comment: If it's running on JRuby in production, why would you test it with anything else?

Comment: because 1.9.3 starts 30 seconds faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

generate those two files and in `.rvmrc` write:

```
source ./.rvmrc_${TEST_WITH:-jruby}
```

then you can write in your shell:

```
export TEST_WITH=ruby
cd .
```

and restore with:

```
unset TEST_WITH
cd .
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems silly.

First, why are you even bothering to run a different Ruby in development? If this is for the occasional test run to ensure compatibility across different Rubies, then okay, but then…

Second, all you probably have in your `.rvmrc` is `rvm use 1.8.7` or `rvm use jruby`—that is all that happens when your `.rvmrc` file runs. What's so bad about just actually typing that out into the terminal? It's actually *less* characters than the example commands you gave, and you get tab-completion too. If you need consistency across shells and actually have to have the `.rvmrc` reflect the current Ruby you want, then just change the file. Or, if you really must, write a simple script to do it for you (say it's called `changervmrc.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "rvm use $1" > .rvmrc
```

and invoke with `./changervmrc.sh jruby`. You could adapt this to include switching to a specific gemset if needed.